# Should a premium PHP script run notice-free?

Tags: php, error-handling

Personally, I always try to ensure my scripts run without any notices at all, but I consider myself to be pretty anal about that sort of thing, and with notices on in development, you can easily spot an miss-spelled variables or other minor problems.

The reason I'm asking this question is that a few premium (ie paid-for) Wordpress plugins I am using from a popular Wordpress plugin site produce *a lot* of notices, sometimes 10+ on a page. **Is this acceptable for something I've paid for?**

It's not hard to do suppress notices like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['var']) && $_GET['var'] == 'foo') {
```

These things could obviously cause more headaches down the line as a script grows.

Comment: Notices SHOULD be fixed, but unless you want to take WP out of the php stone age and rewrite it for modern environments, you're going to be stuck with warnings.

Comment: This question is a bit subjective. I would not be happy to receive code with notices in it, but others may disagree.

Comment: I agree that code generating notices should be fixed. In this case, you're the customer. The customer is always right. So, contact the developer and argue that the product does not meet your expectations.

Comment: It's not acceptable *if* notice-freeness was a pledged attribute when you bought the template. If you only want to *suppress* irrelevant notices, yes, that's not a big deal either.

Comment: There was no specification that the plugins are notice free, but it's certainly not what I expected for paying $xxx for access to premium plugins and themes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should a PHP script run notice-free?

Yes. The feedback is there to help improve your script and catch possible mistakes. Beyond that, it gets very subjective and I'll refrain from posting opinions.

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps a matter of opinion, but I don't think it is acceptable even in an Open Source script which can be used for free.  I remember installing VirtueMart once to find the main index.php littered with E_NOTICE errors.  I simply stopped them from displaying, but that's not really the ideal solution!

As you say, it isn't at all hard to suppress notices, and I believe it should always be done to prevent unexpected bugs from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is totally ok for a script to generate Notices, after all they are only Notices.

They are intended for helping the developer to find bugs, but also show a lot of unnessecary information.

Your example

```
if(isset($_GET['var']) && $_GET['var'] == 'foo') {
```

would be mouch shorter if you wouldn't care about the notice:

```
if($_GET['var'] == 'foo') {
```

This leads to shorter and easier to maintain code (because you don't need to change the name twice if you cange it).

So for me Notices are a tool for finding bugs like a profiler or a debugger. You can use them (and clean your code from the unnessecary ones) or you get rid of your bugs in any other way.

Comment: What if a server is setup to log notices? You'd lose actually disk space everytime this script was run because you have not catered for them.